# In Altair (Python), is there a way to omit the middle values of a bar chart?

Tags: python, altair

I have a bar chart which shows a bunch of values, ranked from highest to lowest. But I have too many (~100). I'd like to make a bar chart that omits middle-ranked values, to show the bars with the highest values, and those with the lowest, not unlike Pandas' default display for a DataFrame, which shows the first 20 or so values, then a `...`, then the last 20 or so. So basically a chart that looks like this:

```
X
XXX
XXXXX
XXXXX ... X
```

I could always make a DataFrame that just omits those values, but it'd be nice to have a visual representation of that omission. Is that possible?

Comment: Once you drop the middle, you can plot it. It is quite questionable approach to expect a viz library would do any data dropping for you, Altair or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way to do it in Altair, but you can hack your DataFrame to provide some visual indication of the discontinuity like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

raw = data.airports()
df = (raw[raw.country == "USA"]
      .groupby("state")
      .iata.count()
      .rename("number_of_airports")
      .sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
     )

top_bottom = pd.concat(
    (df.head(5), pd.DataFrame(data=[["...", 0]], columns=df.columns), df.tail(5)),
    ignore_index=True
)

alt.Chart(
    top_bottom.reset_index()
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("state",
          sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="index", op="sum"),
          axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)
         ),
    y="number_of_airports"
)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Altair grammar does not have a clean abstraction for this kind of chart, but you can do it with a bit of hacking. Here is the same chart shown in @foglerit's answer using Altair transforms:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

raw = data.airports()
df = (raw[raw.country == "USA"]
      .groupby("state")
      .iata.count()
      .rename("number_of_airports")
      .sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
     )

alt.Chart(df).transform_window(
    rank='rank()',
    sort=[alt.SortField('number_of_airports', order='descending')]
).transform_filter(
    (alt.datum.rank <= 5) | (alt.datum.rank >= 50)
).transform_calculate(
    state="datum.rank == 50 ? '...' : datum.state",
    number_of_airports="datum.rank == 50 ? 0 : datum.number_of_airports"
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("state:N",
          sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="rank"),
          axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)
         ),
    y="number_of_airports:Q"
)
```

[image]